# Group by day of year on mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

My documents are stored like this and no, i can't change them:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5ea773f219d60c4f1629203a"),
        "direction" : 135,
        "latitude" : -3.744851,
        "longitude" : -38.545571,
        "metrictimestamp" : "20180201025959",
        "odometer" : 55697826,
        "routecode" : 0,
        "speed" : 3,
        "deviceid" : 134680,
        "vehicleid" : 32040
}
```

I need a group by vehicleid and only the day of year from this "metrictimestamp", and count how many documents are with the same vehicle and day, ideas??

Comment: How did you get this `20180201025959` ? So when you say `day` do you mean `01` from your timestamp ?

Comment: The scenario is : I receive de data like this, and for some reason the date is an long int, and i have to peform this querys without changing the data, and yes, 01 is the day i meant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say your `metrictimestamp` probably would contains first few characters `20180201` as `YYYYMMDD`, So using [$substrbytes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/substrBytes/#substrbytes-aggregation) in aggregation you can get month, day, year from the string. Try below query :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      day: { $toInt: { $substrBytes: [ "$metrictimestamp", 6, 2 ] } }, // $toInt can be optional
      month: { $toInt: { $substrBytes: [ "$metrictimestamp", 4, 2 ] } },
      year: { $toInt: { $substrBytes: [ "$metrictimestamp", 0, 4 ] } }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: { vehicleid: "$vehicleid", day: "$day", year: "$year" },
      count: { $sum: 1 }
    }
  }
])
```

**Test :** [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/k01d3e7Wws2)

Comment: This works perfectly, but other thing, can you help me to put this "day, month and year" in one single key, to be like: _id: { vehicleid, date}

Comment: You can do something like this : date: { $toInt: { $substrBytes: [ "$metrictimestamp", 0, 8 ] } }, Test here :: (https://mongoplayground.net/p/BfKVrd2HNiD)